# Ionic app iOS crashing on publishing

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, app-store

I've create a app with Ionic, it works perfectly in Android and it is in Play Store.

I've tested the app in iOS emulator and in real iPhone and all works fine, but when I tried to publish to App Store, it was rejected, because Apple said that app crash in launch. But in emulator and in real device I launched app correctly.

**This is my cordova config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="1912000202" id="com.traveely.traveely" version="0.2.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Traveely</name>
    <description>FREE trip planner based on your budget and profile.</description>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://www.traveely.com/*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <platform name="android">
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.6.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="~2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.7.4">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="899682943484552" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="Traveely" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.1" />
</widget>
```

**This is the crash log** (It is not entire, because Post chars limit)

```
Incident Identifier: 49087956-E0F4-4C4D-ADFB-6B3C426714C1
CrashReporter Key:   369ff88b4e7a1d96e3e9018f84d323ece0f3dc01
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             Traveely [1828]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5B9F1828-D2FC-407B-AA5B-5C9400916B9F/Traveely.app/Traveely
Identifier:          com.traveely.traveely
Version:             0.2.0 (0.2.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.traveely.traveely [865]


Date/Time:           2016-10-10 06:56:33.8859 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-10-10 06:56:33.7476 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x190ce41c0 0x18f71c55c 0x190ce3e88 0x1916eb1a0 0x197030368 0x190c03dc4 0x19702ed3c 0x197030fd8 0x196db6a04 0x196b9f0a8 0x196db57c0 0x196dca080 0x196db28c4 0x1928858bc 0x192885728 0x192885ad0 0x190c92278 0x190c91bc0 0x190c8f7c0 0x190bbe048 0x196b985dc 0x196b93360 0x100079c94 0x18fba05b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018fcb2014 0x18fc93000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd79460 0x18fd74000 + 21600
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018fc263f4 0x18fbc3000 + 406516
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018f6f12d4 0x18f6f0000 + 4820
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018f70ecc0 0x18f6f0000 + 126144
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018f71c844 0x18f714000 + 34884
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018f70b66c 0x18f6f0000 + 112236
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018f70b234 0x18f6f0000 + 111156
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018f71c71c 0x18f714000 + 34588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190bbe0bc 0x190bb5000 + 37052
10  UIKit                           0x0000000196b985dc 0x196b1d000 + 505308
11  UIKit                           0x0000000196b93360 0x196b1d000 + 484192
12  Traveely                        0x0000000100079c94 0x100074000 + 23700
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018fba05b8 0x18fb9c000 + 17848

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018fcb2a88 0x18fc93000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd7536c 0x18fd74000 + 4972
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd74db4 0x18fd74000 + 3508

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd74db0 0x18fd74000 + 3504

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd74db0 0x18fd74000 + 3504

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd74db0 0x18fd74000 + 3504

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018fc9416c 0x18fc93000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018fc93fdc 0x18fc93000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190c91cec 0x190bb5000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190c8f908 0x190bb5000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190bbe048 0x190bb5000 + 36936
5   Foundation                      0x00000001916ccb1c 0x1916c0000 + 51996
6   Foundation                      0x00000001916ed60c 0x1916c0000 + 185868
7   UIKit                           0x000000019750dc7c 0x196b1d000 + 10423420
8   Foundation                      0x00000001917ca50c 0x1916c0000 + 1090828
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd77860 0x18fd74000 + 14432
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd77770 0x18fd74000 + 14192
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd74dbc 0x18fd74000 + 3516

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018fc9416c 0x18fc93000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018fc93fdc 0x18fc93000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190c91cec 0x190bb5000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190c8f908 0x190bb5000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190bbe048 0x190bb5000 + 36936
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001913abcec 0x1912df000 + 838892
6   Foundation                      0x00000001917ca50c 0x1916c0000 + 1090828
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd77860 0x18fd74000 + 14432
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd77770 0x18fd74000 + 14192
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fd74dbc 0x18fd74000 + 3516

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001740f0e37
    x4: 0x000000018f70fbc3   x5: 0x000000016fd8b590   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x000000018fc3d792  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b5b4ec40  x21: 0x000000016fd8b590  x22: 0x00000001b5b55bb8  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000174019ca0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fd8bbe0   fp: 0x000000016fd8b4f0   lr: 0x000000018fd79460
    sp: 0x000000016fd8b4d0   pc: 0x000000018fcb2014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

Anyone have some similar experience with Ionic and AppStore? How can I fix it to publish my app?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you calling any API in didfinishlaunching method of AppDelegate.m?

Comment: How I writed previously I  use Ionic (hybrid framework based on Apache Cordova for app development), so I'm not programming native app in Objective-C or Swift, so I'm directly not calling nothing in AppDelegate.m

Thank you any way.

Comment: FYI, I am aware of Cordova and ionic framework and i have worked on it. Can you post the code whatever it is in your didfinishlaunch method?

Comment: I've writed AppDelegate.m in question. Anyway this is generated code by cordova, so if I modify it, when I build the app, I will lose any changes I writed in AppDelegate.m.
The app works fine in development but was rejected by AppStore in publishment, I think the code is not the problem, but some permission can be incorrect in config.xml. Reading crash log, I think the problem is about internet conection permission.

Comment: Have you handled anything in your app for offline working?

Comment: No, but without internet conection it doesn't crash and when you are going to do any action, a information popup appears.